# SQL Server query; last record for each ID

Tags: sql-server

i'm looking for a query, which gives me for each ID the last record (based on date, which is given, and timestamp).

In my case, the ID is "knr", so i want the last record of every KNR in event_ap (matched with pers_stm to get the names). 
Im only able to get this result for 1 ID, but not for all of them.

I have this tables (only examples, both tables have over 10 thousand entrys)

```
event_ap

Ereignis   a_nr    tnr    date         time    knr   maschnr
PAN        123     2203   2017-01-23   8:00    11    x222
PAN        132     2203   2017-01-22   8:00    22    x222
PAB        123     2203   2017-01-23   9:00    11    x222
PAN        555     2203   2017-01-23   6:00    33    x222
PAN        555     2201   2017-01-23   11:00   44    x222
PAB        222     2202   2017-01-23   10:00   44    x222

pers_stm

name  knr
Test1 11
Test2 22
Test3 33
Test4 44
```

What i want is this

```
Ereignis  tnr   date       time   knr   name    maschnr
PAB       2203  2017-01-23 9:00   11    Test1   x222
PAN       2203  2017-01-23 6:00   33    Test3   x222
PAN       2201  2017-01-23 11:00  44    Test4   x222
```

my query so far is this. But obviously, with this one i only got the last record of one ID, not of all which match the WHERE clause

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.Ereignis, A.tnr, A.date, A.time, A.knr, A.maschnr, B.name
FROM event_ap AS A
JOIN pers_stm AS B on A.knr = B.knr
WHERE A.knr = '11' AND A.date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '23.01.2017') ORDER BY A.time DESC
```

Thank you for your replies

Comment: because the record was made on 2017-01-22, im only looking for values from 23.01.2017 which is 2017-01-23

Comment: is there logic that ensures that `(knr, date, time)` is unique, or does your query output have to account for two "last" records with matching values?

Comment: wait, do you need the maximum date-time, or just the maximum time for a given date then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last records with this:

```
select * From (
    select * from
    (
      select *, row_number() over (partition by knr order by date desc, time desc) as RN
      from event_ap
    ) X 
    where RN = 1
) Y join pers_stm p pn p.knr = Y.knr
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytic `row_number` function can be used for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
    row_number() over (partition BY knr order by TIME DESC) AS RN
  FROM event_ap
  WHERE DATE = '2017-01-23'
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This assumes that the `TIME` column is of type `time`. If not, use `CONVERT(time ,timecolumn)`